# How reuse oatuh2 in airflow login for other resources?

Tags: oauth-2.0, airflow-2.x, trino

Ok I lauched airflow 2 locally and logined into it via google auth. Then I need to run some logic in airflow that uses trino connection string. Is there a way to get the already performed google auth token and use it in trino connection string?

In total user logged into airflow, runs logic and logic connects to trino with same user.

Is it possible?